# INT32U and INT8U in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting errors withis below declaration.when declared INT32U i'm getting 
errors.

Though **INT32U** and int are 4 bytes.How will i declare the equivalent of INT8U.I cant use int 
here as its **INT8U** is 2 bytes.

```
INT32U_C Uucode(INT8U_C* pDst,const INT8U_C* pSrc,INT32U_C nSrcLen);
```

Error:**Expected '=',','";" 'asm' or '*attribute*' before Uucode.**

Comment: show us the define for INT32U_C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdint.h` has specific-size integer definitions, including uint32_t and uint8_t.